# Browse files on partially formatted drive

Tags: filesystems, partition, files

So I had a customer come in for data restoration when they had an installation fail which resulted in partial data loss.

When booting into a live USB on the machine the drive shows up with `lsblk` as  the correct size for the actual drive, `df` can find the drive but shows the partition as `7.8G` instead of the true ~`120G`.

Here is the results of `lsblk`

```
sdc      8:32   0 119.2G  0 disk
```

And here is the result of `df -h dev/sdc`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
```

Is it possible to either mount the drive or just browse the files to see what I can recover before properly formatting the drive and reinstalling the OS?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  Depends on whether the filesystem is corrupted.

Comment: You might consider using `dd` to make a copy, if you can.  Then, in an emergency, you can do aggressive experiments.  I've had to `emacs` a (copy of a) swap file before to recover data.  It worked, but it was a (really) long shot.